# can you read and write simultaneously into windows phone 8 database?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm developing a cloud-based application in windows phone 8. I bind a view to a table from database (.sdf). The problem comes when new photos are being downloading into this table and the app tries to access to them. To solve this I must put a semaphore but this cause the app runs slow.

(I've tried to do this with a lists, but when there are a lot of photos, it causes an memory overfow, so I'mt trying to do it binding to a database)

I want to try with a SQLite database, but I don't know if it will fix my problem.

There is another way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code, code...did I mention code? How should we help you, if we don't know how you're accessing the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is not a UI thread problem? Sounds like it..

Please try adding: `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( ()=> { savePicture(); } );` at the point you add new picture in the table.